# How to assign the correct typing to React.cloneElement when giving properties to children?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am using React and Typescript. I have a react component that acts as a wrapper, and I wish to copy its properties to its children. I am following React's guide to using clone element: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/03/03/react-v0.13-rc2.html#react.cloneelement. But when using using `React.cloneElement` I get the following error from Typescript:

```
Argument of type 'ReactChild' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactElement<any>'.at line 27 col 39
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any>'.
```

**How can I assign the correct typing's to react.cloneElement?**

Here is an example that replicates the error above:

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface AnimationProperties {
    width: number;
    height: number;
}

/**
 * the svg html element which serves as a wrapper for the entire animation
 */
export class Animation extends React.Component<AnimationProperties, undefined>{

    /**
     * render all children with properties from parent
     *
     * @return {React.ReactNode} react children
     */
    renderChildren(): React.ReactNode {
        return React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
            return React.cloneElement(child, { // <-- line that is causing error
                width: this.props.width,
                height: this.props.height
            });
        });
    }

    /**
     * render method for react component
     */
    render() {
        return React.createElement('svg', {
            width: this.props.width,
            height: this.props.height
        }, this.renderChildren());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 216, accepted):

The problem is that the [definition for `ReactChild`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/949922e0959ccea0cad7a6fa787b63b7d4e67d3f/types/react/index.d.ts#L196) is this:

```
type ReactText = string | number;
type ReactChild = ReactElement<any> | ReactText;
```

If you're sure that `child` is always a `ReactElement` then cast it:

```
return React.cloneElement(child as React.ReactElement<any>, {
    width: this.props.width,
    height: this.props.height
});
```

Otherwise use the [isValidElement type guard](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/949922e0959ccea0cad7a6fa787b63b7d4e67d3f/types/react/index.d.ts#L351):

```
if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
    return React.cloneElement(child, {
        width: this.props.width,
        height: this.props.height
    });
}
```

(I haven't used it before, but according to the definition file it's there)

Comment: @Chris yeah, things are being moved around every once in a while. the current url for it is: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L190

Comment: Got it working with the type guard. But the casting approach still produces some errors fromTS in my code

Comment: Type guard approach is the valid approach.

Answer (score 31):

This solved it for me:

```
React.Children.map<ReactNode, ReactNode>(children, child => {
    if(React.isValidElement(child)) {
      return React.cloneElement(child, props
      )
    }
  }
```

quite simplle solution

Comment: definitely the correct solution, this handle the multiple children case

Answer (score 0):

```
 import React, { Children } from "react";


 const child = Children.only(children) as React.ReactElement;

 React.cloneElement(child, {anyProp:"newProp" })
```

this is type of `Children`

```
interface ReactChildren {
        map<T, C>(children: C | C[], fn: (child: C, index: number) => T):
            C extends null | undefined ? C : Array<Exclude<T, boolean | null | undefined>>;
        forEach<C>(children: C | C[], fn: (child: C, index: number) => void): void;
        count(children: any): number;
        only<C>(children: C): C extends any[] ? never : C;
        toArray(children: ReactNode | ReactNode[]): Array<Exclude<ReactNode, boolean | null | undefined>>;
    }
```