# Pass props to React children in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I would like to loop over the children to my React element and pass custom props. This is not compiling in Typescript per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261783/how-to-assign-the-correct-typing-to-react-cloneelement-when-giving-properties-to). The answer there mentions two solutions, neither of which works for me:

1. When I use `child as ReactElement<any>`, I get: error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ReactElement'. (I use @types/react, but do not import it in the current file, if that matters?)
2. When I use `isValidElement` and actually pass down props, I get:

error TS2345: Argument of type 'ReactElement<{}>' is not assignable to                parameter of type 'ReactElement<{ ranking: any; }>'. Type '{}' is not assignable to type '{ ranking: any; }'.
    Property 'ranking' is missing in type '{}'.

Here is my sample code:

```
  renderChildren() {
    return React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
      return React.cloneElement(child as ReactElement<any>, {
          ranking: this.props.ranking
      });
    });   
  };
```

Have a nice Sunday!

Comment: Of course you need to import it. If you import it like this: `import * as React from "react"` then change it to `React.ReactElement<any>`. Also, the 2nd error just says that you need to use `ReactElement<{ ranking: any; }>` instead of `ReactElement<{}>`.

Comment: Dumb mistake, thank you!