# Typescript: How to properly type an additional prop when we are using React.cloneElement

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
const Test: React.FC = () => (
  <Parent>
    <Child />
  </Parent>
);

const Parent: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const onClose = () => {
    console.log('onClose');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {React.Children.map(children, child => {
        if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
          return React.cloneElement(child, { ...child.props, onClose });
        }
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

const Child: React.FC<{ onClose: () => void }> = props => {
  return <div />;
};
```

There is the obvious error:

`TS2741: Property 'onClose' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ onClose: () => void; }'`

TypeScript requires to add `onClose` property to `<Child/>`. The parent component passes the property using `React.cloneElement`.

Is it possible to solve the problem without using "render props"? How we can type `const Parent: React.FC<>`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to assign the correct typing to React.cloneElement when giving properties to children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261783/how-to-assign-the-correct-typing-to-react-cloneelement-when-giving-properties-to)

Comment: Sorry, It isn't my case. My question is related to passing property and then I use the component in JSX.

Comment: Can you create an interface like `interface SomeInterface {
    child1?:any;
    child2? any;
    onClose?:()=>void;
}` add the child properties and onClose function there , then use `const Child:FC<SomeInterface> =  props => {`

Comment: Yes, thanks I already use such decision but I would like to avoid using the optional parameter here. It will require to use if / else or optional chaining inside Child component. For example: `if (props.onClose) { props.onClose() }`.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?