# Typescript and React: Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-props

I am converting a react project over to typescript and I'm having an issue.  The scenario is this:  I have a series of `Chapter` components.  Each `Chapter` is associated with its own unique data and unique `Map` component. Each `Chapter` renders a `ChapterTemplate`, and passes the `Map` as a prop:

```js
// Chapter.tsx

import model from './modal';
import Map from './Map';

type ChapterProps = {
    data: ModelSchema;
    map: ReactElement;
};

const Chapter: FunctionComponent<ChapterProps> = () => {
    return <ChapterTemplate data={model} map={<Map />} />;
};
```

This is giving me the following ts error at `map={<Map />}`:

`Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'. Type 'Element' provides no match for the signature '(props: { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any>'.`

I am not sure how to type this prop based on how I am using it.

For some context, here is what a `<Map />` component should look like:

```
type MapProps = {
    metadata?: {
        name: string;
        theme: string;
    };
    mapState?: {
        center: number[];
        zoom: number;
        basemap: any;
        layers: any[];
    };
};

const Map = ({
    metadata,
    mapState: { basemap, layers, zoom, center },
}: MapProps) => {
  
  // ... custom logic here for each chapter ...

}
```

Ultimately it is the `ChapterTemplate` component that organizes the data, manages the state, and passes certain pieces of data to the `Map` as props using `React.cloneElement`:

```js
const Chapter = ({
  map,
  data: { pages, metadata },
}: ChapterProps) => {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);
  const Map = map;

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      // Some other stuff in here
      <MapContainer>
        {cloneElement(map as null, {
          mapState: pages[currentPage].mapState,
          metadata,
        })}
      </MapContainer>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

I read the question [How to assign the correct typing to React.cloneElement when giving properties to children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261783/how-to-assign-the-correct-typing-to-react-cloneelement-when-giving-properties-to), which is where I got the idea to use `ReactElement` as the type for my `map` prop.  I tried using `map as ReactElement<any>` in my `cloneElement` call but it was still giving me errors, so I gave up and put in `as null` for now.  But I am still getting this error.  For the record, the code does work and compile - react is happy with my syntax and organization.  But is typescript trying to tell me something about the way I'm using a component as a prop?  Is there a more proper way to do this?  Thanks for reading.

Comment: Please correct me here but in `ChapterProps`,  `map` is `ReactElement` not `FunctionalComponent` or `React.FC` but during the evaluation in `map={<Map />}`, `map` is an element, instead it should be of type Component.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure.  I thought it should be considered a `Component` or `FunctionalComponent`, and I've tried defining it those ways in the type definition.  But that is not having any effect on the errors I'm getting.

Comment: check the comment here t.ly/MixL

Answer (score 1):

Check the code [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiArgHYbATEDCE4FSxWiqGAogDZIj3wC+cAZlBpwARFGYwRAbgCwAKBgBPMEjiUAFijAwkUAApCwAZzgBeXPLhW4AExQwUALjgpii2XOtwQW58nQw7JzcHjwe8koqcACyWgYQxmYWntZcDnYOAPzOOJZe1sQoXM5GMFDAxADmHvnWMOrBJWUV1XlWYW3eWgDKDjrZybVWaNy6zsSEIABGugDaALo1QwBeEDTjkzNQS7VTKEacvi5uO-lsKIq6Rs6uigunHXKP8mgUpTFaSQAUuSlWaSgMihMJ0fGBevYkCCns5YmB4sYAJRmAB8gzg4hghCgxDgXwAPDZgAA3FEACSQbDYEDgAHdoGwbPiAPRE0mI0LyF5veAaLQ6KAAFU4YHOOm+vy8QOhXjB0J4OVs9icx0U2DBziIpBg5CoNEgxG4PGRpjReGZzLgaE0VVU9WAJhgNP8rA4XAYeUx2NxBLZ5Mp1LpDKZrJJKI58h4XLkr2I7z52jGBBIZAo1FohoY+ITAoRRjR5i+YEMRhNZs6XpxcGzmkTQpFYtUQNMOGLCSMADogXwwS38XC4MyUXwh6EPEgAB6QWC2JD8FCENi82sCqRAA), it's the issue of mismatching type `ReactElement` vs `FunctionalComponent`

Update:

Hey can you change it to

```
const ChapterTemplate = ({
    data,
    map,
}: { data: any, map: FunctionComponent<MapProps>}) => { // change this to ReactElement
  return (<div>Hello world</div>);
}

const Chapter: FunctionComponent<ChapterProps> = (props) => {
    return <ChapterTemplate data={props.data} map={Map} />;
};
```

and then do the `<Map />`

or do this

```
const ChapterTemplate = ({
    data,
    map,
}: { data: any, map: ReactElement}) => { // change this to ReactElement
  return (<div>Hello world</div>);
}

const Chapter: FunctionComponent<ChapterProps> = (props) => {
    return <ChapterTemplate data={props.data} map={<Map />} />;
};
```

Comment: I have tried assigning `map` as `FunctionComponent`.  It does not have any effect on the error.  In fact, in the code sample you linked, its giving the exact error I'm getting at `map` on line 35.  Thanks for setting that up, now you can really see the issue.