# How to use props.children in React.clone with typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have been trying this since a while, searched many stack questions but could not find the solution. I have the following code:

```
          export const RadioGroup: FC<RadioProps> = ({ children, name,
          ...props }) => {
            return (
            <RadioContainer> 
              {React.cloneElement(children, { name })}  
            </RadioContainer>
            )
          }
```

I am getting error in children of cloneElement above. It shows red underline. I have the following interface for RadioProps:

```
    export interface RadioProps extends StyledSystemProps{
      checked?: boolean;
      name?: string;
      children?: React.ReactChild | React.ReactChildren;
    }
```

And here is how I am using it:

```
         <RadioGroup name="class" value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
              <Radio value="first"  />
              <Radio value="second" />
              <Radio value="third" />
              <Radio value="fourth" />
            </RadioGroup>
```

My question is how can I use props.children in React clone without getting any error. I ve tried using props.children just children but nothing works. Can anyone please guide?
Is there any other way I can pass down the props to children. I simply want to pass the name prop of RadioGroup to the Radio elements.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261783/how-to-assign-the-correct-typing-to-react-cloneelement-when-giving-properties-to